# How can I interface GridDB with other databases like PostgreSQL and MongoDB for Real-Time Analytics?

Tags: griddb

I need to interface GridDB with other databases in our infrastructure, like PostgreSQL and MongoDB. I want to transfer data between these databases for various analytics and reporting purposes.

I've looked through the documentation but didn't find any information on external integrations or interfacing with other databases.

My question is,
Are there built-in features or tools in GridDB for interfacing with other databases?
What are the recommended approaches or tools for transferring data between GridDB and other databases like PostgreSQL or MongoDB?